# Bash script to make ssh becomes easier

Tags: bash, ssh

I'm managing hundreds of network devices, and when i want to ssh to a device, I need to type in my jump server **"ssh -l $user $ip/dnsname"** in terminal.
I have an idea that's write a bash script and run it as a service. When I want to ssh to any device, I just need to type the IP address or DNS device name in the terminal and hit enter. It will execute the ssh command automatically.
But i'm new in bash, could you guys please give me an instruction?

Comment: Store the usernames in your ssh config file. Then typing three characters before the address of the computer costs you practically nothing (or gives you a saving if you configure your shell to autocomplete hostnames after ssh).

Comment: do you have to use bash? any other languages are you familiar with?

Comment: If you're really going this route, just look for bash tutorials. I don't think anybody wants to retype a tutorial for you, and link-only answers are frowned upon cause links can break, making the answers useless. Please check also [ask].